# Phonejs route param with array

Tags: javascript, html, phonejs

Recently, I use phonejs to develop a new project.

And I want to transfer parameters in different view, I know it can define the route like:

```
AppNamespace.app.router.register(":view/:personId/", { view: "view_home",personId:'' });
```

However, when I want transfer an array in different views, it seems not so realizable. What is the best way to transfer an array in different view?

Can anybody help? Thx : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the array to the app namespace and access it on any view...

```
AppNamespace.MyArray = [Whatever...]
```

This will be accessible anywhere via AppNamespace.Myarray